# how to make a website change based on device?

Tags: javascript, html

so i wanted to make my website load differently on desktop and mobile. The code below detects whether its loading on mobile or desktop. Is there any way i can replace the `you are using moblie` text to a whole new html code so that when the website loads on mobile instead of showing `you are using mobile` it load a new html website meant for mobile?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        var element = document.getElementById('html');
        if (isMobile) {
            
              element.innerHTML = "You are using Mobile";
              
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = "You are using Desktop";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is "mobile"?  What is "desktop"?  What about all the devices that are somewhere in between?  What is your actual goal here?

Comment: i mean do you expect me to list all devices that are out there?  my goal it to display different design website for different devices like mobile and desktop.

Comment: The screen resolution is much more relevant than the user agent. Modern websites are "reactive" and generally use CSS @media queries to control the look and feel across all types of devices.

Comment: No, I expect you to be specific with what you're asking, and explain the *why*, or it's difficult to give you a good answer.  If you're simply trying to change some styling, consider CSS media queries instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to redirect to another html page just use window.location='https://yourmobileurl.com' in your if statement or window.location='https://yourdesktopurl.com' in the else

HOWEVER, a better way to design this is to use media queries